# why isn't the absolute div not positioning to the fixed div?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to position the blue div relative to the red div.

I used the absolute position for the blue div but it didn't move relative to the red div
this is the html code.

```css
.mench {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mench" style="position: fixed;top: 25px; left: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
<div class="mench" style="position: absolute; left: 25px; background-color: blue;"></div>
```

Comment: A picture of your entire desktop is a waste of world-wide silica :) the runnable snippet already previews that output. Removed the useless image.

Comment: To use relative positioning you need to use position: relative and enclose the blue inside the red.

Comment: both are out of the flow so there is no related between them. In general, there is never a relation between any absolute or fixed element (unless they are parent/child)

Comment: I think you don't need position fixed or absolute any of these here. You need to explain what your target is.

Comment: You can't position siblings relative to each other with `position`. You also can't position any element relative to another `fixed` element, because `fixed` takes an element out of the document flow and gives it its own unique flow altogether.

Comment: What do you want the outcome to look like? Can you use other CSS properties to manually position both how you like, and then explain your constraints (like "red div must be position: fixed or 10% of the viewport off the left edge of the screen")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.mench {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mench" style="position: fixed;top: 25px; left: 100px; background-color: red;">
  <div class="mench" style="position: absolute; left: 25px; background-color: blue;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mench {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.mench::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 75px; /* 50 + 25 = 75 */     
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mench" style="position: fixed;top: 25px; left: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

I understand that you're looking for clarification on what to do in case the answer I provided isn't aligned with what you were expecting. To address this situation, here's a clearer way to convey the information:

If the response I've given doesn't match the answer you had in mind, here's what you can do: Please feel free to provide additional context or ask follow-up questions to guide me better. This will help me understand your perspective and provide you with a more accurate and satisfactory response. Your input is valuable, and I'm here to assist you to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.mench {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.red {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mench" style="position: fixed; left: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
<div class="mench" style="position: absolute; left: 25px; background-color: blue;"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Never just dump code and expect everyone to understand what it was that you did

Comment: if you want  the blue div to be 25px away from the left side of the red div put left:175px because red is left: 100, + 50 = 150 so left must be 175px

Answer (score -2):

Just remove 'top: 25px' from the red div

Comment: The  problem doesn't get fixed, I want the blue div to be 25px away from the left side of the red div.